# Best practices for embedding an application in a website

Tags: web-development, web-applications

I've written an embedded app in Javascript/HTML/CSS that allows people to schedule services. Here is an example installation in production right now:
https://azureautodetailing.com/schedule-online.php

I've clearly made some bad architectural decisions.

I designed it to install itself directly onto a website. Each website that I install it on, I have to spend a few hours messing with CSS conflicts. Also, it uses jQuery, and jQuery-UI. Some websites already have this installed and some don't, the ones that do inevitably have their own versions of jQuery that may or may not work with the app.

How is this kind of thing handled by people who know what they're doing? Are they using an iFrame? What design principles do people generally follow for this type of use case?

Comment: Ever heard of containers?

Comment: *Cry in [scoped css](https://www.caniuse.com/style-scoped).* A well configured [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) works well (there are some security considerations).

Comment: Yeah I'd start with an IFrame.